# Referencing static object - alignment trap triggered on ARM proc

Tags: c++, arm, memory-alignment

I have a class:

```
class A {
public:
    static A& instance();

    ...
    void setValue(int val){ _value = val; }
private:
    int _value;
}
A& A::instance(){
  static A _Instance;
  return _Instance;
}
```

I am running this on an ARM processor. The issue I am encountering is that the application is triggering an alignment trap in the kernel when I call the instance() method from a particular class (say class B). If I call instance() from anywhere else, I do not encounter the alignment trap.

> Alignment trap: not handling instruction e28fc609 at [<0001b588>]

I can see how this would happen if I were casting pointers to mis-aligned values, but I am simply referencing a static object. One would assume that the access would be correctly aligned.

Note the class is grossly simplified. It contains a *lot* of member variables and methods (not my design!).

Does anyone have any suggestions on where I may be going wrong, or where to look?

Comment: @MM Have you experimented with making `A::instance()` non-inline?

Comment: Have tried running only this code in the compiler? Does it fail in the same way?

Comment: @aix - Actually in the code the method is not implemented in-line. I have updated the code above. Cheers.

Comment: @daramarak - yes I've tried, and it succeeds. In fact, the reference is retrieved using this method in many places in the code. It is only in one particular place that it fails.

Comment: Can you find out which asm instruction (or, at least, which C++ statement) triggers the exception?

Comment: @atzz - The C++ statement is A::instance() from within a specific class triggers the exception.

Comment: To me, here does not seem to be any "legitimate" reason for alignment exception. I'd suggest going down to assembly level. If you can, post an excerpt of disassembly around the point of exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys. It turns out the root cause of this problem was a segmentation fault. The disassembly showed that the alignment trap pointed to the fault signal handler subroutine. I'm looking into why this happened now, but the question I originally asked is no longer relevant.